# Php multi array search

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I search a value in a multi dimensional array.

I would like to receive all keys looking for a specific date Ex(2012-07-25) in [created]

and receive array[0][0] and array[0][1]

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id_store] => 3
                [id_product] => 11
                [monitored] => 0
                [created] => 2012-07-25
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id_store] => 3
                [id_product] => 12
                [monitored] => 0
                [created] => 2012-07-25
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id_store] => 4
                [id_product] => 11
                [monitored] => 0
                [created] => 2012-07-26
            )
    )

)
```

Comment: the user notes for array_search() have several examples: http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work with [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter):

```
$target = '2012-07-25';
$matches = array_filter( $array[0], function( $el) use( $target) {
    return $el['created'] == $target;
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but it should work:

```
$results = search_date($my_array, $my_date);
```

`

```
function search_date($array, $date, &$result=array())
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        if($key == 'created' && $value == $date)
        {
            $result[]=$array;
            continue;
        }
        if(is_array($item))
        {
            search_date($item, $date, $result);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Personally, I would ditch your data format altogether and use an object model more suited for the task.